# Python Package not including everything

Tags: python, anaconda, install.packages

I'm using Anaconda and Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have created several packages and one of them is named `mybasics` where I keep some classes and tools that I use over and over.

The package is a work in progress as I come fully up to speed with Python after years of PHP. I originally created the package with only 2 files which contained a few classes in each file. The directory which holds those 2 files now holds several other files as well.

The issue I'm having is that for longest time when I imported and do `dir(mybasics)` only the original 2 files appear. I have rebuilt the package via `python setup.py install` several times. The `python setup.py install` appears to work for changes within those 2 files but did not include any of the new files.

The package directory is like this:

```
/home/gabe/python/lib/mybasics/
  ./bin
  ./build
  ./docs
  ./mybasics
    __init__.py
    cBaseClass.py
    cBeanstalk.py
    cHelpers.py
    ...
  setup.py
```

The `setup.py` file is simple:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='mybasics',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='G Spradlin',
    author_email='gabe.spradlin@{removed}.com',
    packages=['mybasics'],
    package_dir={'mybasics':'mybasics'},
    scripts=[],
    url='',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='Basic Python functions and Classes.',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
)
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Sep  9 16:15:29 2014

@author: gabe
"""
```

So as I was writing this post originally none of the new files were working. Spyder crashed and I brought it back up. Voila all but the newest file now imported as expected. So I rebuilt it using 'python setup.py install' again, shut down Spyder, rebooted the machine. Still no go on the latest file.

I'm wondering if there is something about packages I'm missing. It really only seems to be in this package. I have a couple of others that are also works in progress and I don't remember ever having this issue with them.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: `python setup.py install` does not "rebuild" a package, it installs it to system site-packages (which might not be a good idea).

Comment: So what is the recommended way of rebuilding a package? Do I need to uninstall it and reinstall?

Comment: What I mean is that uninstalling and installing is orthogonal to "building a package".

Answer (score 0):

When you import a package, it does not automatically import all the submodules in that package. You need to import them to your `__init__.py` file, or explicitly `import mybasics.cBaseClass` and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this prior to writing the post and again after just in case. I can use `from mybasics.cBaseClass import BaseClass`. That isn't working for the modules that are missing though.